# Remove borders between patches in image

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I want to use a pre-trained network on 256x256x3 images to make predictions on larger images. The idea is to apply reflect padding to the image so that the dimensions are multiples of 256x256x3, divide the image into 256x256x3 patches and make a prediction for each patches. The problem is that even after joining the patches, the edge of the image is still visible. Is there a way to avoid this? I have tried applying filters or overlapping, but the problem persists.

This is the function I use for the prediction:

```
def prediction(model, image):
    height, width, channel = conf.train_set_conditions[3]
    h_img, w_img, _ = image.shape
    print(image.shape)

    patch_size_x = int(((h_img + 31) // 32 * 32) / height)
    patch_size_y = int(((w_img + 31) // 32 * 32) / width)

    pw, ph = (h_img + 31) // 32 * 32 - h_img, (w_img + 31) // 32 * 32 - w_img
    padded_img = image
    if pw != 0 or ph != 0:
        padded_img = np.pad(image, ((0, ph), (0, pw), (0, 0)), 'reflect')
    results = []
    for i in range(patch_size_x):
        for j in range(patch_size_y):
            start_row, start_col = i * height, j * width
            end_row, end_col = start_row + height, start_col + width
            img_part = padded_img[start_row:end_row, start_col:end_col]
            img_part = np.expand_dims(img_part, axis=0)
            result_part = model.predict(img_part)
            results.append(result_part[0])

    # Join the parts back into one image
    reconstructed_img = np.zeros_like(padded_img)
    for i in range(patch_size_x):
        for j in range(patch_size_y):
            start_row, start_col = i * height, j * width
            end_row, end_col = start_row + height, start_col + width
            result_idx = i * patch_size_y + j
            result_part = results[result_idx]
            reconstructed_img[start_row:end_row, start_col:end_col] = result_part
    #reconstructed_img = filter_image(reconstructed_img, 3, 0.5)

    if pw != 0 or ph != 0:
        img_predicted = reconstructed_img[ph // 2:h_img + ph // 2, pw // 2:w_img + pw // 2, :]
    else:
        img_predicted = reconstructed_img

    return img_predicted
```

And this is what I get, as you can see some lines near the junction. Don't pay attention to the beauty of the image, the training was done on different images, I'm just testing the results.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KPQU.png)